# Using `mutate_at()` with `as.Date()`

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use `mutate_at()` from `dplyr` to coerce date-like columns into columns of type `Date` using `as.Date()`, but I'm getting an error. Here's the code:

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(date_1 = "7/5/2014", date_2 = "7/22/2011")
df %>%
    mutate_at(.vars = c("date_1", "date_2"), .funs = as.Date("%m/%d/%Y"))
```

This gives me an error: `Error in charToDate(x): character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

Not sure what's going on here, so I'd appreciate your help. I prefer `dplyr` solutions, but if there's a better way to do it, I'm open to that as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally prefer using the syntax as so:
The `.` here refers to the column, which needs to be passed to the `as.Date` function.

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(date_1 = "7/5/2014", date_2 = "7/22/2011")
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(date_1, date_2), funs(as.Date(., "%m/%d/%Y")))
```

Comment: `funs()` is soft deprecated as of `dplyr 0.8.0` - can instead do: `mutate_at(vars(date_1, date_2), as.Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: Could you please update to the current tidyverse syntax which uses list(), please?